# display formatted html inside razor view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm loading from database certain property which holds formatted html. Inside razor view I'm loading property using razor helper

```
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
```

but that renders this formatted html like

```
some text, sometext <br><br> <b>more bolded text</b>
```

what I want is to use this html tags and display formatted like

```
some text, sometext 

**more bolded text**
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a different method or the HTML will be interpreted. Use @Html.Raw(Model.Description). This should write out the HTML.